# Blog posts use the wrong icon in the feed on the mobile apps (both Android and iOS)

Tags: bug, android-app, ios-app, android-app-feed, ios-app-feed

Today in the feed on the Android Stack Exchange app there is a Stack Overflow blog post. This post had the site icon next to it for [Tridion](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/) rather than the proper site logo (Meta).

> [image]

Stack Exchange Android App Version 1.0.73 and 1.0.74
Android 5.1 on a Moto X (2013) running stock firmware.

Same behavior on a Nexus 7 (flo) running Android 6.0 (stock).

This issue also happens on the iOS app.

---

The most recent featured SO blog post (as of 17 Nov) is showing up with the "edX" site logo.  The logo is seemingly randomly incorrect.

Comment: I encountered this on the iOS app too - [see here](http://imgur.com/duRft6c)

Comment: Obviously a bug in the API itself, returning wrong URL. Nothing the apps can do, API should be fixed

Comment: Technically this post is about the whole Stack Exchange network.  "Stack Overflow" is the name of the company.  The problem here is that the blog post was featured on Travel (and every site, really) so the feed is just saying "Look, this blog post was featured on Travel!"

Comment: @BrianNickel well if it is network wide the right sidebar on all of the sites manage to show a meta.SE icon where the mobile apps fail to do so.

Comment: @casey Fair enough.  Looking at the web, it looks like it has access to whether a blog post is site specific or global and uses that logic to pick the icon.  I'll see about moving that logic to the feed.

Comment: @Brian did you ever get anywhere with that? [Seems to still (or again) be a problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286262/307988)

Comment: @Cai thanks for finding the duplicate.

Comment: @Cai [tag:status-not-important-enough]