# Featured blog in Stack Exchange app appears to be part of Italian SE

Tags: bug, android-app, ios-app, android-app-feed, ios-app-feed

Right now, when I look at the feed in the Stack Exchange app, the featured blog [#92](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/10/Stack-Overflow-92-Podcast-The-Guerilla-Guide-to-Interviewing/?cb=1) seems to be part of [Italian SE](http://italian.stackexchange.com). It's not just the logo; when I tap on it, it takes me to the Italian SE questions. This behaviour occurs both on iOS and Android, so it's probably an API issue.

[image: Feed in Stack Exchange iOS app showing the blog with Italian SE logo]